# Redirect 404 to search page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Becouse in google webmasters I have 550.000 not found pages - 404 - I want to make some redirections to the search page.

To be userfoul for the users, need to go to the search page, but is realy complicated for me, becouse I need to EXTRACT the search phrase from the 404 url:

Here are the 2 type of url with 404 errors, and need to be redirected.

- DOMAIN/movie/12298295-Iron-Man-3

  DOMAIN/serie/15108-The-Walking-Dead/seasons/3/episodes/10

Of corse, I need to extract **JUST THE NAME** of the movie, or the serie and redirect to this url

- DOMAIN/search?q=Iron-Man-3

  DOMAIN/search?q=The-Walking-Dead

---

Well this is the URL by parts:
For "movies" just have 4 parts:

- DOMAIN - of corse, is the domain name of the website

  /movie/ - is created based on the content type (movie or serie)

  12298295- is the ID for this item and can be form - 1 - to
  infinite

  Iron-Man-3 - the name of the movie (is wath I want to get)

For "series" - THE SAME like for the movies, but at the end can have more parts, and the full URL can be: (all this url, for an normal page with NO 404, are ok)

- DOMAIN/serie/15108-The-Walking-Dead/seasons/3/episodes/10 - Link to episode page

  DOMAIN/serie/15108-The-Walking-Dead/seasons/3/ - Link to some season page

  DOMAIN/serie/15108-The-Walking-Dead/ - Link to the TOP page for this serie

---

Please note, I need to redirect this url, JUST if the result is an 404 page (ErrorDocument 404), becouse the same type of url are used in all pages.

Here is my actual .htacces

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php[^/] /$1? [L,R=301,NC,NE]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? [L,R=301,NC,NE]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q= [NC]
    RewriteRule ^busqueda\b /busquedas [R=301,L,QSA]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The following shall work for both movies and series:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:movie|serie)/\d+-([^/]+) /search?q=$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: NO - this rule redirect ALL url's with - movie|serie , like I have tell in this question, many other similar url's are ok, for example, DOMAIN/movie/123-title , can result in an 404, becouse this entry is deleted, but DOMAIN/movie/456-title is ok, so need to redirect ONLY if the result is 404

Comment: @user5535624 The 404 is triggered by a script in the case above. It'd need to be handled by the script itself. Apache will never know whether the movie/series existed or not in database.